# using particular word of <p> element in html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p> this is a car</p> //HTML p element
```

Is there any way that I can use the word only that I click on e.g if I click on car only 'car' is used. if I click on this only 'this' is used. i.e. the only word that I click on.

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">This is a car</p>

myFunction() {
    var my;
    my=document.getElementbyID("demo")[1]; //to get 'is'
}
```

p.s I need to use only a single word that is clicked. My p element contains at-most 10 words.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have an answer, but an idea. You don't need to select the parent element by ID but you need to get the click position (from the event object, `myFunction( event )`) and then try to get the word that was covered by the cursor in the moment of the click…

Comment: `document.getElementbyID` should be `document.getElementById` but not a solution though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your paragraph only contains text, you can use a small script to prepare the paragraph by splitting it into words :

```
var element = document.getElementById('demo');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.split(' ').map(function(w){
  return '<span class=w>'+w+'</span>';
}).join(' ');
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.w'), function(w){
  w.onclick = function(){
    alert(w.innerHTML);
    return false;
  }
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/xiyodobelo/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: i have used it according to my need that i have to replace the input text word by the word that is clicked.it is working but the issue is when i click 'this' the p element gets replaced by this 
**class="w">is class="w">a class="w">car**

Comment: @eliya I don't understand your problem. Did you look at the demo ?

Comment: what i want is when i click on any word of the p element,the input text box of my html page gets replaced by that clicked word and the p element is set to empty string. Hope i am making my point clear

Comment: @eliya Checkout the [updated demo](http://jsbin.com/yuxexesefo/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: hi there.
is there a way to add in this function that after the clicked word enters the text box, the text box gets activated and i can further write into it directly without clicking on the text box?
i.e to give control to the text box

Answer (score 1):

Its easy if you consider `double click` event instead. You need to use `dblclick` event in Javascript to achieve this.

Checkout the code snippet below:

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('dblclick', function getSelectedText() {
  var selectedText = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }

  selectedText = selectedText.trim();
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = selectedText;
});
```

```html
<p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Selected text = <span id="result"></span></p>
```

Answer (score -4):

Put the word car in the span element - onclick should go in the span.
Like this:

```
<p id="demo">This is a <span id = "demo_car" onclick="myFunction()>car</span></p>
```

Comment: To do this for every single word – which may get clicked – seems like a huge effort.

Comment: The OP wrote: "I need to use only a single word that is clicked" so I assumed they only needed to do this for one word